# "Of the order of" notation

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions

I have a function where all terms have the same coefficient $x^3$ in it:

For example
$f(x) = ax^3 - bx^3$

Can I say that in big $O$ notation:

1. $f(x) = O(x^3)$
2. $f(x) = O(x^3)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$
3. I cannot say that.

Also, Can I say that in little $o$ notation:
$f(x) = o(x^2)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: 2. is correct, 1. too but ambiguous (where are the asymptotics taken with regard to? It'd be true everywhere in this case, but leaving it implicit is bad practice). Try to show it from the definition of $O(\cdot)$? (as a hint: by the triangle inequality, $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leq (\lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert)\lvert x^3\rvert$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: Provided $a\neq b$, **#2** is correct.

Comment: @NgChungTak Even if $a=b$. Then $f=0$, and the constant zero function definitely satisfies 2.

Comment: @Clement C. Thanks. I can use equal sign directly?

Comment: @kww What do you mean?

Comment: @kww Incidentally: after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\color{green}\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with: whenever you want to use asymptotics, always specify *where* the asymptotics are taken. I.e., it is when $x\to a$, for some $a\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$: it may be clear in context, but if not you need to state it (typically, $0$ or $\infty$). This rules out 1., just because it's ambiguous (although, as we will see, if you did specify where, it'd be correct in your case).

Now, for your specific example: for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, by the triangle inequality
$$
\lvert f(x)\rvert = \lvert a-b\rvert \lvert x^3\rvert \leq 
(\lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert) \lvert x^3\rvert \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
so, by definition of the $O(\cdot)$ notation (take constant $C>0$ equal to $\lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert$, or even $\lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert +1$ to discard the case $a=b=0$) we do have
$$
f(x) = O(x^3) 
$$
when $x\to 0$. (For that matter, also when $x\to \infty$, or even  $x\to a$ for any $a$). So **2. is correct** (regardless of the values of $a,b$).

*Note:* if $a\neq b$, you even have the stronger statement $f(x) = \Theta(x^3)$ when $x\to 0$ (or, again, $x\to a$ for any $a$).

**Second question:** can you write $f(x) = o(x^2)$ at $0$? Again, let us check with the definition:

> $f(x) = o(x^2)$ when $x\to 0$ if there exists a non-negative function $\varepsilon$ such that $\lvert f(x) \rvert = \varepsilon(x)\lvert g(x)\rvert$ and $\varepsilon(x)\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} 0$.

Well, let's use $(\dagger)$ again, with $\varepsilon(x)\stackrel{\rm def}{=} (\lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert) \lvert x\rvert$. This satisfies both conditions, so that *indeed* 
$$
f(x) = o(x^2)
$$
when $x\to 0$. (Now, you can check that this will not be true when $x\to \infty$, unless $a=b$. In this case, $f=0$, and this is trivially true.)

Comment: This is a really nice answer. I would only like to remark that some authors adopt the convention that $O(\cdot)$ does in fact not need a *point* to be specified where it holds. But rather that $f = O(g)$ means the inequality holds over the entire domain. (This domain needs to be clear though. Though sometimes this can be implicit.) And $f= O(g)$ for $x\mapsto a$ means "$f= O(g)$ on some neighborhood of $a$."

Comment: Mmmh... thanks for the precision (I had never seen it used to specify that on the whole domain). Under that definition, then 1. is correct (although I would still recommend against it, at least in my field -- theoretical computer science. There are already enough abuse of notations and implicit assumptions about the notations, and I have never seen this one used there.)